# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory" not login in cloud 9

Tags: django-allauth

django-allauth been used

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'xxx:index'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'account_login'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = ''
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'tttt@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
```

I set this in settings.py and I runserver, sign up and then received an email such as

```
You're receiving this e-mail because user jjjj@gmail.com has given your e-mail address to register an account on example.com.


To confirm this is correct, go to https://eeee.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/accounts/confirm-email/4444/
```

so I go to the link but then I cannot login. Instead, I receive another mail and I got no error message. I am sure that I use ID and password correctly. What should I do?

Cloud 9
Python 3.7.9
Django                 2.2.17
django-allauth         0.44.0

When I go to the link in VERIFICATION, I like to login.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by myself. The order of url in urls.py was wrong.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    re_path(r'^accounts/confirm-email/[^/]+/', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='timeline:index'), kwargs=None),
]
```

is a right order.

re_path(r'^accounts/confirm-email/ should come after path('accounts/',